# C++ Error reading file

Tags: c++, scanf

txt file  
(Name\t\tScore)

something like:
Jacob        25
Thomas       48
etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   
    FILE *f = fopen("skore.txt","r");
    if (f==NULL){
        cout << "err " <<endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char* meno= "                             ";
    int skore;
    while(fscanf(f,"%s\t\t%d",meno, &skore ) != EOF){
        cout << meno << ", " << skore << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

But, when I run it:
**Unhandled exception at 0x61fade8f (msvcr100d.dll) in SLDTemplate2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0097ca4c.**

Comment: do you have permission to read a file?

Comment: This is why `char *` pointing to a string literal is forbidden in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

You must not try writing to a string constant!

```
// Bad
char* meno= "                             ";

// Good
char meno[31] = "                          "; // 30 chars + 1
```

Comment: @JakubWulpBelis, Just use a `std::string` and `std::ifstream`.

Comment: @JakubWulpBelis: note that the answer already includes the answer to your follow-up question: you can use a `char` array, in this case explicitly sized.